# Gate level Verilog syntax

Tags: verilog

I have the following initiation in gate level Verilog.

```
bufx2 BH2_BUF (
  .A(\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice[4][5] ),
  .Z(\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice_4__5_3) 
);
```

In my poor understanding "Z" pin of buffer is connected to : "\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice_4__5_3"

1.But the connection of "A" is not clear.
2.Should be there space between [4] and [5] or not?

Comment: There should be a whitespace before the closing parenthesis: `.Z(\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice_4__5_3 )`

Comment: The main problem what is: (.A(\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice[4][5] ) And should be space beetween [4] and [5]

Comment: What isn't clear? Why do you think there should be a space? Why are you happy with the connection to `Z`, and not `A`?

Answer (score 3):

Synthesis tools can perform two operations on your design:

- **Flattening**: They convert your hierarchical design into a single module in which there is no hierarchy. In this case, all signal names in the flatten module corresponding to signals in the non-flatten module `mux_inst.aggr_portd_inst.dskw_inst` will have the prefix name: `\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst`. The '\' is used to escape '/' character.
- **Bit-blasting**: Bit-blasting is the term for breaking down a bus/array into its individual members. For example, an array which was originally defined as `logic [2:0] array` will be broken into:

  ```
    logic \array[2] ;
    logic \array[1] ;
    logic \array[0] ;
  ```

Again, the '\' is used to escape '[' and ']' characters. If they array was two-dimensional, you would have:           `logic \array[2][0] ;`, which acts like a single wire corresponding to member [2][0] of the array.

In your case, it looks like the synthesizer performed both flattening and bit-blasting.

There might be a rare occasion, where the synthesizer performs bit-blasting on only one dimension and keep the other dimension as an array. In that case, `\array[2] [0] ;` has a different meaning than `logic \array[2][0] ;`. The former is the member 0 of an array called `\array[2]`, whereas the latter is a single wire which was the result of bit-blasting, corresponding to the index [2][0] of the array before bit-blasting.

Answer (score 0):

With Verilog binary words each bit can be accessed with an array like syntax.

```
//Create 24 bit word
reg [23:0] a_word;
reg a_bit;

//Access the MSB (bit 23)
initial begin
  a_word    = 24'b0;
  a_bit= a_word[23] ;
end
```

Extra dimensions can be add, the most basic 2 dimensional array often being called a memory. Here with syntax used previously the first `[]` access a word, using double `[][]` we access a single bit.

```
// Create 24 bit 10 deep memory
reg [23:0] a_memory [0:9];

integer i;
initial begin 
  for (i=0, i<10, i=i+1) begin
    a_memory[i] = 24'b0;
  end

  //Access a word
  a_word = memory[1];

  //Access a bit
  a_word[4] = memory[1][4];
  a_bit     = memory[1][4];
end
```

Therefore if `ds_mem_slice` is declared as a memory then `\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice[4][5]` is accessing a single bit of it. Word 4 bit 5.

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear it's meaning and I see that no space is needed between [4][5].

Comment: @Morgan: Depending on what the definition of `\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice` is, a space may or may not be necessary. If `\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice[4]` is the name of a vector, then `\mux_inst/aggr_portd_inst/dskw_inst/ds_mem_slice[4] [5]` is accessing its 5th bit, in which case a space is necessary.